# How to make a tool bar like the Spotify app?

Tags: xml, kotlin

This is my code:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="181dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradiant_background">


        

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/tool2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Liked Songs"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

I think Spotify has two toolbars one toolbar collapses when scrolled, and the second one is always pinned on top. It shows the back button and title, but in my codes when I add a toolbar in a collapsing toolbar. The `scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed` doesn't work anymore. I'm using a recycler view.